# How can I get Craft Commerce talk to the API of a CRM?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

A client wants his CRM connected to Craft Commerce. If someone finishes an order the customer data and the ordered products should be send to the CRM.
I assume I have to write a plugin for that, but I have no idea how to start and how the grab the desired data. Can anyone point me to the right direction? The CRM used is https://www.bitrix24.com/ if that's of importance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a plugin to perform the integration. If you make it generic enough, you could share it with the community.

Your plugin would use Craft Commerce **events** to run PHP code at specific points in the code, which would communicate with the third-party systems.

Docs on event:
https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference

The event you would probably be most interested in is the `onOrderComplete` event:

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onordercomplete

Comment: Has there been any development on this lately? I am a little impatiently waiting for full two way API on Craft Commerce's products and other entities.